# to find the highest sal employees and add only those employess in target by using IICS or informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-data-integration-hub

My source is like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afeZp.png)

```
emp_id name  sal
101    tina  10000
102    mega  10000
103    meena 5000
```

I need the details of the employees 101 and 102 details:---like this

```
emp_id name  sal
101    tina  10000
102    mega  10000
```

Comment: Please, provide table data and structures in text format. Check this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also you should include what code do you have so far.

Comment: You can use sorter, aggregator combination to chosse emp with highest salary - first order by id and salary in desc order and then agg by id. You can use SQL override to pickup highest as well.

Answer (score 0):

Read the data, use Aggregator to find max value, and join the max with the original data set.

```
Src-SQ----Agg--\
      \---------Jnr---Tgt
```